# Low-battery-power action without gnome-power-manager

Tags: laptop, hibernate, suspend, power-management, battery

I'm running the openbox WM and would like to avoid loading the gnome stack.  One of the lingering issues I have to resolve is avoiding abrupt system crashes due to depleted battery power.

Is there a low-profile, low-dependency daemon that will handle this situation?  I'd like to be able to configure it to, for example, drop the system down into hibernation at 4% battery life if the AC is not connected.

I suppose I could just write a little cron job to poll `/sys/.../batt*/..` and `/sys/.../ac*/...` every 10 minutes or so, but it seems like there might be some edge cases that need tending.

#### update

[`laptop-mode-tools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/laptop-mode-tools) sounds promising:

> It ... supports various ... power management features, such as ... automatically hibernating if battery levels are too low...

However, [it doesn't seem to be possible to install it in Maverick without relatively dire consequences](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/laptop-mode-tools/+bug/638307).

On my system, its installation also requires the removal of the `acpi-support` package, which sounds sort of ominous.

Answer (score 1):

You are very probably already running it:  `acpid`.  If the GNOME or KDE stuff is already installed then you'll find a bunch of ACPI event handlers already in `/etc/acpi/events` and scripts run in response to those events in `/etc/acpi` itself; you can modify or replace those scripts with your own handlers.

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a lot of documentation included with Ubuntu about what events are available, and the handlers I see provided with `acpid` and `acpi-support` don't appear to include anything that tracks the battery level.  Since ACPI should be providing events for that, you may have to experiment with `/usr/share/doc/acpid/examples/default*` to see what events are actually delivered so you can write handlers for them.

Comment: Hmm.. found an example at <http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/acpi/acpi-low-battery-warning.html#acpi_event>.  Though I'm not sure I understand when the event(s) `battery.*` get triggered.  Also I was hoping for something that would abstract away all the gritty polling and `/proc/**/*` bits.

Comment: Hm, `acpid` should be doing that for you; the ACPI BIOS sends the `battery.*` events, and you would have an `/etc/acpi/events/battery` which selects for `battery.*` events and runs a script to act on them.  The script examines the name of the event to see what triggered it, and if it's a "battery low" event should do a shutdown or suspend.

Comment: Okay, maybe I just didn't read that article in enough detail.. I kind of skimmed it.

Comment: Hmm.. what I mean is that there is not actually a "battery low" event, you have to poll some system-dependent resource in `/proc` or `/sys` to find out why a battery event was generated.  At least it looks that way:::::: I just dropped down to 0% battery capacity (according to `wmbattery`).  I've set up an event handler `/etc/acpi/events/log-all-events` that responds to `event=.*` with a call to `/usr/bin/logger '%e'`.  The only event that was registered when I hit 0% capacity was `battery BAT0 00000080 00000001`.  The exact same message is generated when I connect or disconnect the AC.

Comment: I use the term "poll" loosely there, since it's not actually going to be checking every minute or whatever.  But it will be required to check every time the AC connection status changes.. and more to the point, it will be required to check, period, when I was hoping it would just get the message from ACPI that the battery was low.

Comment: More detail: the only messages that have been logged during the 12 hours or so that I've had that event handler active, with the exception of the above-mentioned low-battery-power message, have been in response to AC connection and disconnection.