# What actions does Ubuntu trigger when battery is low?

Tags: gnome, power-management, battery, dbus

When the battery is low, the screen gets dimmed after a few seconds already.

This appears to be some special power-saving mode, and might be related to the time in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.time-low` (1200 seconds (20 minutes) the default).

While this seems to get triggered by gnome-settings-daemon, I wonder what else Ubuntu does when this happens (e.g. via DBus listeners), or other event listeners that look for a "low battery" state.

It seems like something in this regard causes Ubuntu / X / the system to behave more sluggish afterwards (when the laptop is on AC again), and I would like to look into what might be causing this.

I could not find anything related via `dconf-editor`, e.g. in org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.

It appears to get setup via `idle_configure` in plugins/power/gsd-power-manager.c, but it's probably something more related to something that listens on the DBus interface, which gets notified via e.g.:

```
    if (!g_dbus_connection_emit_signal (manager->priv->connection,
                                        NULL,
                                        GSD_POWER_DBUS_PATH,
                                        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                                        "PropertiesChanged",
                                        props_changed,
                                        &error))
```

I could imagine that some "power saving" property gets set, but not unset when AC is available anymore and/or the battery is not low anymore.

I have looked at the CPU governor setting (`/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`), but it was `ondemand`.

I am using `gnome-settings-daemon` with awesomeWM on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
gnome-settings-daemon=3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.1
```

I've also compared gsd's plugins/power/gsd-power-manager.c with the one from Debian's gnome-settings-daemon-3.12.1, but could not find anything obvious that might have been fixed/changed in this regard.

I have managed to trigger the gnome-power-manager's gnome-settings plugin (which dims the screen etc), by patching upower and use it after killing the system's upower daemon.
(note that it's probably only `energy` that is being used by gpm to calculate it by itself).

It does not make the system become sluggish..

OTOH I have not heard the speaker's beeping, which might come from the BIOS, which might be involved here, too - or other programs using the kernel's interface on `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/`.

```
--- src/linux/up-device-supply.c.orig   2014-06-07 16:48:32.735920661 +0200
+++ src/linux/up-device-supply.c    2014-06-07 16:48:39.391920525 +0200
    @@ -821,6 +821,9 @@
        supply->priv->energy_old_first = 0;
    }

+   percentage = 3.1f;
+   time_to_empty = 3*60;
+   energy = 5;
    g_object_set (device,
              "energy", energy,
              "energy-full", energy_full,
```

Comment: You might also wish to examine acpi events: this appears to be related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33062/low-battery-power-action-without-gnome-power-manager

Comment: This is interesting as well `cat /usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs`

Comment: @ElderGeek I only have `/usr/share/acpi-support/state-funcs` on my system. `policy-funcs` is available in `acpi-support-base` (but only for Debian).

Comment: Added 14.04 tag to your question.

Comment: This page features intersting script, power.d hook:   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you should look into `tlp` and `tlp-rdw`, and what they can *have Ubuntu do when there is low power*.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the "Power" tab in System Settings, you have the option to choose what happens when the battery reaches a critically low level. You can, with standard Ubuntu, make it power off when critically low. If you have hibernation enabled (Check out this link for instructions: [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)), you can also make the computer hibernate. If in doubt about the difference between suspend and hibernate, look at this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660436

I hope that I have been of service.

-Mario3D13

Comment: That is the standard user-facing stuff / settings, which are not related to the problem I am/was seeing.  I have noticed this issue (sluggish / slower) lately, when the laptop was suspended while on battery and then resumed on AC.  But it is not reproducible and might only be related in the symptoms.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Concernig your complete question, I can't really answer it (I'm still not an all-out power user, still have stuff to learn)